# What's available in the calling environment of a function while building a package?

Tags: r, package

I have run into quite a peculiar issue when trying to add a specific attribute to some of the functions in a R package I'm building.

Basically, I wish to add an attribute that includes all the classes the function is to be called on. This can either be specified manually or, and this is the tricky part, it can be done by looking up what methods are available for that function.

I can do this by writing something like

```
foo <- function(x) UseMethod("foo")

foo.character <- function(x) x
foo.numeric <- function(x) x + 1

makeAttributedFunction <- function(fName, classes = NULL) {
  if (is.null(classes)) {
    theseMethods <- as.character(methods(fName))
    if (length(theseMethods) > 0) {
      classes <- sub(paste(fName, ".", sep=""),
                     "", theseMethods)
    } else classes <- character()
  }
  f <- get(fName)
  attr(f, "classes") <- classes
  class(f) <- "attributedFunction"
  f
}

foo <- makeAttributedFunction("foo")
```

which works just fine when I run it directly in the console, then it get

```
> foo
function (x) 
UseMethod("foo")
attr(,"classes")
[1] "character" "numeric"  
attr(,"class")
[1] "attributedFunction"
```

However, if I do this in a script that is included in a package, `makeAttributedFunction()` no longer seems to be able to find the methods associated with `foo()`. Calling `foo` (which is in package `fooPack`) now returns

```
> fooPack:::foo
function (x) 
UseMethod("foo")
<bytecode: 0x0000000019ec7100>
<environment: namespace:fooPack>
attr(,"classes")
character(0)
attr(,"class")
[1] "attributedFunction"
```

I have tried getting a glimpse of what is available in the environment while building a package by including a `browser()` line in `makeAttributedFunction()` and calling the `check()` function from `devtools`. This allows me to debug `makeAttributedFunction()`, but I'm not really certain it's in the "right" environment and it doesn't really help me. Here are some of the things I have tried:

```
Browse[1]> fName
[1] "foo"
Browse[1]> methods(fName)
no methods found
Browse[1]> get(fName)
function(x) UseMethod("foo")
<environment: namespace:fooPack>
Browse[1]> foo.character
function(x) x
<environment: namespace:fooPack>
Browse[1]> foo.numeric
function(x) x + 1
<environment: namespace:fooPack>
Browse[1]> isS3method("foo.numeric")
[1] TRUE
Browse[1]> parent.env(as.environment(-1L)) 
<environment: namespace:fooPack>
Browse[1]> ls(parent.env(as.environment(-1L))) #all objects in the namespace of fooPack
[15] "foo"                        
[16] "foo.character"              
[17] "foo.numeric"                
[18] "makeAttributedFunction"     
Browse[1]> .S3methods("foo", envir = parent.env(as.environment(-1L)))
no methods found
```

Any ideas or pointers to what is going on here will be greatly appreciated - and either way, thanks for reading!

Comment: I'm not sure why you're going to all this trouble when the S3 and S4 object frameworks already exist.

Comment: My reason for doing this is that I wish to create a framework where people  (e.g. unexperienced users) can create functions and add the classes manually to the `classes` attribute. The `classes` attribute is not a complete list of what is possible, but should rather be thought of as a guideline to what is intended. It's part of a bigger system of code where I believe this functionality is needed.

Comment: But no matter if you agree that this is a good strategy, I'm still quite puzzled by what is going on here. I would love to understand why my `methods()` call within `makeAttributedFunction()` behaves the way it does when called during package building.